# What does * means in the list from the ls command?

Tags: ls

[image]

**Why do `.sh` files have an * next to them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the file is executable.

Reference: [General Output Formatting](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html)

Answer (score 1):

The * means that the file is executable